# Pasar valores de un input a otro input con javascript

Tags: javascript, php

quisiera pedir ayuda con los siguiente:

tengo un input donde el usuario selecciona el mes/año y en ese mismo input le envio un valor de base de datos que es un numero de cuenta:

```
<input type="month" class="btn btn-outline-secondary rounded" onchange=" cambiarReporte(this.value, <?php print($column['cue_cuenta']); ?>)">
```

Entonces quisiera saber como puedo hacer con javascript que cuando el usuario seleccione un mes/año y cuenta, valla a otro input esos dos mismos valores

```
 <a onclick="ReporteHistorico(aqui los valores del input anterior mes/año y numero cuenta);" id=" printHistorico" class="descargarHistorico"><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> Descargar histórico</a>
```

alguna idea de como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

entiendo que lo que necesitas hacer es algo similar a lo siguiente suponiendo que tenes un input con id "input_destino".

```
ReporteHistorico(fecha,cuenta){
  document.getElementById('input_destino').value = fecha+cuenta;
}
```